# Is outputcached action result expired *immediately* after the dependency breaks?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-cache

I'm looking to set views dependent on cached objects so that when they are *expired or explicitly removed from cache* the cached result is immediately expired so that there is no chance the outdated HTML is rendered.

For that, I'll be using:

[this.Response.AddCacheItemDependencies(myCacheKeysArray);](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h3ee2kh2.aspx)

Is it guaranteed that the outdated action result will never be returned?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. It takes a long a while before the action result outputcached is expired. On my computer 15 seconds but this will probably vary on certain factors like machine and available resources.